# In Oracle ATG, how can I prevent logged in user againto login

Tags: java, atg, atg-dynamo, oracle-commerce, atg-droplet

In oracle ATG, how can we prevent a user who is already logged into the site from login again. In my application if the user is logged in and if he comes back to login page and try to login again it is showing invalid session. Can we disable this in atg?

Comment: Can you clarify: Is the problem that the users are able to access the login page?  Or are you asking how you prevent users from logging in again once they are logged in?

Comment: Is the login page itself rendered by your ATG app?

Comment: Yes I need to prevent user from execute handleLogin method again if the user is logged in. How I had done is checking whether the profile is transient inside handle login I want to understand whether we have any default atg implementation for this like RepeatRequestMonitor.

Comment: The RepeatingRequestMonitor is to prevent a user from submitting the same form multiple times e.g. a user who clicks login twice in rapid succession.

Comment: You can override `preLoginUser` method and return appropriate message if user is Transient.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to achieve what you want:

1. You could include logic on the jsp which contains the login form fragment to include different fragements based on whether the user is logged in or not e.g. if the user is logged in include a fragment which says "You are already logged in or similar"
2. You could use the `Redirect` droplet e.g.

   ```
   <dsp:importbean bean="/atg/dynamo/droplet/Switch"/>
   <dsp:droplet name="Switch">
    <dsp:param name="value" param="Profile.isTransient"/>
   <dsp:oparam name="false">
      <!-- redirect to another page -->
      <dsp:droplet name="/atg/dynamo/droplet/Redirect">
        <dsp:param name="url" value="http://www.acme.com/alreadyLoggedIn.jsp"/>
      </dsp:droplet>
   </dsp:oparam>
   <dsp:oparam name="true">
     <!-- do nothing -->
   </dsp:oparam>
   </dsp:droplet>`
   ```